# Showing webistes in own app is legal or not?

Tags: android, google-play, privacy, policy

There is a webview in one of the activity in my android application. In which I want to show other websites such as news website, journals website, etc. Is it legal or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legal questions are off topic.  Consult a lawyer.

Comment: yes it's okay, as long you're following google's developer policy https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/user-data/

Comment: if you need to show content from other websites... then have a link display the website off your app. i wouldnt keep it within.

Comment: @DroiDev I want to show news websites in my app.

Comment: are you putting advertising on your app?

Comment: @DroiDev Yes, my apps has banner ads.

Comment: then thats your problem. illegal? maybe...contact a lawyer.. unethical? yes.  you are getting paid (maybe) from ads based on other peoples writings.... and the extent of your code is just taking a website and puttigng it into a web view. learn java, learn apis, learn parsing, get FREE content, then create an application. if you have to ask a question like this, then the odds are, its wrong.

Comment: @DroiDev Ok, I got it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal issues instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

In the news sites, you can get the site's RSS and display it without having to view the entire site
This will save you the volume of data received and the speed of application and also fully legal
How do you get RSS support?
Here's this [RSS](https://www.androidauthority.com/simple-rss-reader-full-tutorial-733245/)